# app engine entitymanager.close() causes npe in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to update an entity in the datastore but when mgr.close gets called, the entity manager is null.

I don't set the entity manager to null anywhere in the code. I don't think that app engine is setting the entity manager to null for me either, it just seems like the entity manager may have crashed or something on its own.

Does the entity manager have a life cycle or something I am not aware of? Is there something I could be doing in the code to make the entity manager close prematurely?

While waiting on this question to be answered I noticed that my update method (generated by cloud endpoints and then altered by myself) didn't have the contains method that checks to see if the object is already present in the datastore. I edited the method and got the same error except it occurred inside the contains method. The code is displayed below.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "updateParty")
public Party updateParty(Party party) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    //update party with serving url             
    try {
        if (!containsParty(party)) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
        }
        if (party.getFlyerServingUrl() == null && party.getFlyerStr() != null) {
             blob = new BlobKey(party.getFlyerStr());        
                options = Builder.withBlobKey(blob);
                servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
                party.setFlyerServingUrl(servingUrl);       
        }
        mgr.persist(party);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return party;
}
```

contains method:

```
private boolean containsParty(Party party) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        if(party.getId() == null){
            contains = false;
        }else{
        Party item = mgr.find(Party.class, party.getId());
        if (item == null) {
            contains = false;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}
```

**EDIT**
**updated DEBUG level stack trace for the second set of methods:**

```
2014-03-05 10:20:40.484 /_ah/spi/com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.updateParty 500 15ms 0kb Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.16.0-rc (gzip) module=default version=1
75.108.229.93 - - [05/Mar/2014:10:20:40 -0800] "POST /_ah/spi/com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.updateParty HTTP/1.1" 500 117 - "Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.16.0-rc (gzip)" "incrowdmobile.appspot.com" ms=15 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000013 app_engine_release=1.9.0 instance=00c61b117c5f081d6ff00df1aac468f916fc26
D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet execute: serviceName=com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint methodName=updateParty
D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService findService: com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint => com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint@2c3abe
D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.ConfiguredObjectMapper$Builder build: Cache hit, reusing ObjectMapper
D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet execute: serviceMethod=Method: public     com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party     com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.updateParty(com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party)    , Resolved Return Type: class com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party, Resolved Parameter     Types: [class com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party]
    D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService findService:     com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint =>     com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint@2c3abe
    D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.ConfiguredObjectMapper$Builder build: Cache hit, reusing     ObjectMapper
    D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService findService:     com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint =>     com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint@2c3abe
    D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.474
com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader read: requestBody={"Id":{"appId":"s~incrowdmobile","complete":true,"id":"5317797651415040","kind":"Party"},"featuredPosition":0,"flyerStr":"AMIfv968K2J3isP3BSq67ru69rgCgnDkA0n0Fq1rqk8XhvuqeAItMXImE9JI-trSr3RxMEkLswCRAZib_FnsVtF3BVrCtVmJtkxDnSmIcgIKtcXhq1KNsOxy3EnWEdBc73boMhGr4EcVQqZhbPhiTru81JEtPqX-G-MZCQzw6lb4tyforoGVII8","flyerUploadUrl":"https://incrowdmobile.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6bB660x2WmQHniLC84sjVvyOwlGwJEGLWCbp6-tBbalHrqo6vmc0lSDeR0CY18kOmphXxAZf5FGV9Lb5Hw2Ln74ZDCUX1DCmxiwS1QHv3iGXWTjqzg60hA5W34x_RSzklXtq3M3/ALBNUaYAAAAAUxdtHwJEZ3edBNcVIp_G5tbuCBUYtJ6o/","genre":"Electronic Dance","headPromoterId":"24001","headPromoterName":"Kreshendo","isClaimable":false,"location":{"latitude":30.088441848754883,"longitude":-95.11273193359375},"maxAge":0,"minAge":0,"partyHashtag":"#hdvfcdg","partyLocation":{"latitude":30.088441848754883,"longitude":-95.11273193359375},"partyName":"hfcdcvh","promoTeamId":"0","id":{"kind":"Party","appId":"s~incrowdmobile","id":"5317797651415040","complete":true},"kind":"partyendpoint#resourcesItem","etag":"\"o5z31f-yQaEVGsxCvjrmPxs4_Z4/I4PX-YUoH_IOu_T_IRwC_CBHXwQ\""}
    D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.475
com.google.api.server.spi.request.ServletRequestParamReader deserializeParams: deserialize: class com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party@f2869f injected into unnamed param[0]
    D 2014-03-05 10:20:40.475
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: params=[com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.Party@f2869f] (String)
I 2014-03-05 10:20:40.479
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: cause={0}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3KeyBatcher.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3KeyBatcher.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:102)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:176)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$1.<init>(Batcher.java:270)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:270)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchGet(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:301)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:280)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:29)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:56)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.get(WrappedDatastoreService.java:60)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.getEntityFromDatastore(EntityUtils.java:665)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:543)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManager.java:1638)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadUnloadedFieldsInFetchPlan(JDOStateManager.java:1363)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.detach(JDOStateManager.java:2718)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.performDetachOnCloseWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4571)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.performDetachOnClose(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4534)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1105)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
at com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.containsParty(PartyEndpoint.java:440)
at com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.updateParty(PartyEndpoint.java:393)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
E 2014-03-05 10:20:40.479
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:49)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3KeyBatcher.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:111)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3KeyBatcher.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:102)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:176)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$1.<init>(Batcher.java:270)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:270)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchGet(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:301)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:280)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:29)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:56)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.get(WrappedDatastoreService.java:60)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.getEntityFromDatastore(EntityUtils.java:665)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:543)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManager.java:1638)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadUnloadedFieldsInFetchPlan(JDOStateManager.java:1363)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.detach(JDOStateManager.java:2718)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.performDetachOnCloseWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4571)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.performDetachOnClose(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4534)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1105)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
at com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.containsParty(PartyEndpoint.java:440)
at com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.PartyEndpoint.updateParty(PartyEndpoint.java:393)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724
```

Comment: It may not be feasible, but is the project small enough to switch from JPA to JDO?  There is justification elsewhere for preferring JDO.  The switch might enable some other developers to try your code scenario (admittedly a personal bias).  Or it might just work ;-)

Comment: no, this project is pretty large.

Comment: So your entity manager is null? ... and where did you set that variable to null?, assuming it was non null from getEntityManager(). AppEngine can't set the variable for you since that variable exists in your method. This is what a debugger is for. If having an NPE, I'd expect you to actually post it with stack trace.

Comment: @DataNucleus thanks for your response. I don't set the entity manager to null anywhere in my code. I hope I added enough information to clarify my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so from the stack trace the EntityManager is NOT null. If sending off requests to the datastore then look in the LOG (at DEBUG level) for what request is sent.

Comment: @DataNucleus ok I've set the datastore to debug level and updated the post with the new stacktrace. I don't really know what I'm looking for though...

Comment: It says nothing to me (there should be a line that Google's JPA plugin outputs, but that's not shown there). All i'd check is if valid values are being input to their low level API method, and if that blows its brains out then get Google to fix their library for that condition (whatever it is)